# Navigate to previous page/url if it exists

Tags: angular

I am currently using Location to navigate back through my application.
Which means there is a Back button displayed in corner which when clicked triggers goBack() function.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(
    public location: Location
  ) {}

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Sometimes though there is no previous page so user is given impression there is when the button is displayed.

How can i determine if there is no page?

This will enable me to hide the button that is currently displayed.

I am using Angular 5

Comment: maybe if you'd get a way for know how many states you have and also what is the order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to router event in service and inject that service inside your component. When component activates, get the previous url from service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouterService {
    previousUrl: string = 'none';
    constructor(
        private router: Router
      ) {
        this.router.events
          .subscribe((event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
              this.previousUrl = event.url;
            }
          });
      }
}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-some',
    template: `<span *ngIf="prevUrl !== 'none'>Back</span>`,
    styles: [``]
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    prevUrl;
    constructor(private routerService: RouterService) { 
        this.prevUrl == routerService.previousUrl;
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```